# When I write while it gives 'do' as well, how can I write while and for equations without getting do

Tags: luatex

```
\While{t $<$ maximum number of iterations}
\For {each search agent}
   \State Update the position of current search agent by equation
\EndFor
\State Update a,A and C
\State Calculate fitness of all search agents
\State Update \textit{W$_{\alpha}$}, \textit{W$_{\beta}$} and \textit{W$_{\gamma}$}
\State t=t+1
```

Comment: welcome to TEXSE. Could you make your scripts compilable?

Comment: In add to Raajas comment: there are many ways to do pseudocode. As long as you only post a sniplet like this we cannot help, we don't know which packages etc you are doing. Thus, please post the usual (on this site) full but minimal example others can copy and test as is.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why did you set the tag "luatex"? Your pseudo-code fragment does not appear to have a self-evident connection to LuaTeX.

Comment: A separate comment, about your coding practice for math-y objects: do please replace `\textit{W$_{\alpha}$}`, `\textit{W$_{\beta}$}` and `\textit{W$_{\gamma}$}` with `$W_{\alpha}$`, `$W_{\beta}$`, and `$W_{\gamma}$`.

Comment: This edit is not something we can copy and test as is. There is no document class, preamble, and normally pseudocode is written inside special environments, which are also missing.